# Angular2: What does paired selector do in @Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I have some question about @directive of angular 2,

[I'm following this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jecelynyeen/how-to-implement-custom-validator-confirm-password-in-angular2-rc-3-622288ba809d#.x6pzssooo)

1-  If selector has to be like this:

```js
selector: '[validateEqual][formControlName],[validateEqual][formControl]
```

and validateEqual is has to be in constructor like this

```js
 constructor( @Attribute('validateEqual') public validateEqual: string,
    @Attribute('reverse') public reverse: string) {
}
```

what does it mean also What is @Attribute

also if there is multi = true in provider and useExisting

Comment: Hard to see what the actual question is or how many question this are.

Comment: These questions are from code for angular2 rc.3 form, trying to understand these things from code :)

Answer (score 1):

- selector: this means that the directive matches elements that have the attribute `validateEqual` and one of `formControlName` or `formControl`
- `@Attribute` injects the value of an static attribute.
  Normally attributes are read into a directive using `@Input()`. `@Input()` also supports bindings where the input is updated when the value bound to a property (or attribute changes). `@Input()` values are available in `ngOnInit()` or `ngOnChanges()` while values injected with `@Attribute()` are available in the constructor but aren't updated if they change later.
  With the following code `@Attribute('validateEqual') would set`public validateEqual`to`foo`

```ts
<div validateEqual="foo" formControlName="bar">

<!-- this doesn't work with `@Attribute('validateEqual')` 
     because the attribute value is not static -->
<div [validateEqual]="foo" formControlName="bar">
```

- `multi: true` means that one provider token provides an array of elements. For example all directives for router support `routerLink`, `router-outlet` are provided by `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`.
  If a new provider is registered with the token `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, then it overrides the previously registered directives. If `multi: true` (on the first registered **and** tjhe new provider) is set, the new directives are added to the previously registered directives instead of overriding.
  When `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` is injected (`constructor(@Inject(ROUTER_DIRECTIVES) directives) {}`) an array of directive instances is injected. It usually doesn't make sense to inject `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`. I used it just as an example because it is `multi: true`.

Comment: I think the author using old style of dependency injection

Comment: What do you mean by "old style"?

Comment: I mean paired selector, not using "@"input, using "@"inject we could have done using "@"Injectable, also multi = true and useExisting these all are now depreciated now

Comment: Paired selector is fine if you want to target elements that have a combination of attributes. Not using `@Input()` is often not what you want but `@Attribute()` still has its place. It depends on your requirements. `@Injectable()` is something entirely different. `multi: true` and `useExisting` are **not deprecated**. `new Provider()` or `provide()` is deprecated but you can just use `MyMockService, {provide: MyService, useExisting: MyMockService}` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138584/analogue-of-angular-2-provider/38138620?noredirect=1#comment63707534_38138620

Comment: I have just finished understanding forwardref by this article http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html they are saying forwardref are for classes that just declared and not defined but later in the code below, but the tutorial im following its '@'directive and class below it, that we normally do like in '@'constructor, i think forwardref is unnecessary in the code of tutorial, M i right?

Comment: The use of `forwardRef` seems legit. `forwardRef(() => 
      EqualValidator)` refers to `EqualValidator` which is only declared 3 lines below. You can't refer a class in the same file before it is declared (before `class MyClass {}`)

Comment: I mean we also do like this with, '@'Component and then below we export class, and you know we don't use forwardref with '@'Component, then why in '@'directive

Comment: It is not about `@Directive()` or `@Component()` it is about referencing the component class (self) from the `@Directive()` or `@Component()` decorator. Normally you reference **other** classes (from other files or above in the same file) but not the class where the decorator is applied.

Comment: Can you tell me what is token, in this line: "With multi providers, we can basically provide multiple dependencies for a single token"

Comment: When you add a provider you can either add the type like `providers: [MyService]`. In this case `MyService` is the token (the key the class is registered with DI) **and** the "value" that will be injected at the same time. You can have a token that is different from the value. A token can be a string or an [`OpaqueToken`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html). If you want to use a token, then you register the provider like `{provide: 'mytoken', useClass: MyService}`.

Comment: If you use a token you need to use `constructor(@Inject('mytoken') someName:MyService) {}` because DI can't derive the key from the parameter type because it differs from what the provider was registered with. Especially with `multi: true` you need to use a token when the values are not of the same type like it is with `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` or similar.