# Analogue of Angular 2 Provider

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components, angular2-formbuilder

I have a custom component for checkbox.

```js
const CheckboxValue = new Provider(
        NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent),
        multi: true
    });

@Component({
               ...
               providers: [CheckboxValue]
           })
export class CheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    ...
}
```

As I understood in RC3 Provider was marked as deprecated. How I must rewrite my Component so that he working after next update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now takes an object like:

```js
const CheckboxValue = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent),
    multi      : true
}
```

**Update**

If you get "No value accessor for ''" in RC.3 new forms see [Custom component binding: No value accessor for ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895474/custom-component-binding-no-value-accessor-for)

Comment: Thanks. But what about providers in bootstrap?

Comment: Nothing special about it. You can use this in `bootstrap(xxx, [...])` or `providers: [...]` as well. A single type like `MyService` is still supported as well.

Comment: So things like *provide("API_URL", {useValue: "some-value"})* still be working?

Comment: `provide()` is also deprecated but you can use `{...}` the same as shown in my answer instead.